# What does it mean for netstat -t

Tags: windows, netstat

I see the help of `netstat -t` option says `Displays the current connection offload state.`

And I tried it in the windows command console.

The `Offload State` value display `InHost`.

What does `Offload` means to `netstat`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

It refers to the TCP Chimney Offload feature which you can enable and disable on a network adapter. `InHost` means that the feature is disabled and offloading is *not* occuring. `Offload` means that TCP Chimney Offload is enabled on the NIC on which that connection is established.

> TCP Chimney Offload overview
>
> TCP Chimney Offload is a networking
>   technology that helps transfer the workload from the CPU to a network
>   adapter during network data transfer. In Windows Server 2008, TCP
>   Chimney Offload enables the Windows networking subsystem to offload
>   the processing of a TCP/IP connection to a network adapter that
>   includes special support for TCP/IP offload processing.

To view the current status:

[image: netsh int tcp show global]